# Automating Graphing and Anova with R

Tags: r, anova

I'm trying to automate a simple graphing and ANOVA analysis with R.  I know I'm not curing cancer here, but I'm trying to read in a CSV file with R, make boxplots with each column, and finally do an ANOVA analysis of each column based on the tissue type.  Here is my input data that I import as `allgenedata`:

```
Tissue  CRX OTX1
Adult Native    589.497 67.8812
Adult Native    553.367 74.7154
Adult Native    643.803 219.045
Adult Native    841.547 77.3731
Adult Native    587.122 155.827
ARPE-19 608.039 7.12757
ARPE-19 450.873 22.2396
ARPE-19 439.412 100.643
ARPE-19 443.038 94.8932
ARPE-19 373.148 68.9125
ARPE-19 447.053 32.9599
ARPE-19 548.943 34.6704
ARPE-19 541.505 41.2435
fetal RPE   605.409 23.3124
fetal RPE   606.874 97.7009
fetal RPE   735.176 68.0812
fetal RPE   946.355 97.5761
fetal RPE   636.287 17.0996
fetal RPE   551.927 48.1705
fetal RPE   499.641 49.6281
fetal RPE   559.901 99.4383
fetal RPE   526.228 119.276
fetal RPE   564.149 37.0931
fetal RPE   521.574 89.9984
fetal RPE   548.483 114.12
native fetal RPE    733.783 52.8845
native fetal RPE    751.961 38.0715
native fetal RPE    1061.66 8.80557
native fetal RPE    771.166 124.042
native fetal RPE    891.287 40.9265
native fetal RPE    901.234 5.3587
```

Here is the code I'm using to analyze this data-

```
genenames = names(allgenedata)
> for ( i in 2:length(genenames)){
+ temp = genenames[i]
+ print(temp)
+ boxplot(temp~Tissue, data=allgenedata)
+ temp.aov = aov(temp~Tissue, data=allgenedata)
+ TukeyHSD(temp.aov)
+ }
```

I get an error saying- 
`[1] "CRX"
Error in model.frame.default(formula = temp ~ Tissue, data = allgenedata) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Tissue')`

I don't understand why i'm getting this error.  Any help you have is appreciated.

Comment: The error is saying that you column lengths in `allgenedata` are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that when you try to do something like `boxplot(temp~Tissue, data=allgenedata)`, R is using the variable `temp` you created rather than referring to that column in `allgenedata`. For the `boxplot` and `aov` commands, just change `temp` to `allgenedata[,temp]` to make sure R knows what you are referencing.

Also, as written, you are overwriting your `temp.aov` and losing your Tukey test each time the for loop runs. To keep the ANOVA  and Tukey tests for each column you should do something like this:

```
temp.aov=list()
tukey=list()
genenames = names(allgenedata)
for ( i in 2:length(genenames)){
  temp = genenames[i]
  boxplot(allgenedata[,temp]~Tissue, data=allgenedata)
  temp.aov[[i]] = aov(allgenedata[,temp]~Tissue, data=allgenedata)
  tukey[[i]]=TukeyHSD(temp.aov[[i]])
}
names(temp.aov)=genenames
names(tukey)=genenames
```

Then, to view your ANOVA tables, you can use `sapply(temp.aov,summary)` and to view your Tukey tests you can call `tukey`.